# Perl Session management

Tags: perl, session, cgi

I am using [`CGI::Session`](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI%3a%3aSession) for session management in my Perl web application. I am able to
create a session using the `file` session driver but I am unable to get the existing session and unable to access stored parameters of session.

I am trying to get existing session but it's creating new one
and query string `$CGISESSID` both are same but `$session` here I am getting was different
it's a totally new one so I am unable to get the stored parameters from session.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Krishna

Comment: Typical first-time mistake here: you are not sending the session cookie to the client/user 1) at the right time, 2) at all. As Borodin said, without seeing your code there isn't much anyone can do to help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting new session at each request, as others pointed out, you are not sending session id in the cookie. If you are using CGI.pm to handle your HTTP header, do this:

```
print $q->header(-cookie => $session->cookie);
```

If you are using CGI::Application for your Application framework, do this inside the setup() or cgiapp_init() (if you have it)

```
$self->header_add(-cookie => $session->cookie);
```

Or, you can use CGI::Session's own header(), which by default, uses' CGI::header method:

```
print $session->header()
```

Using CGI::Session's utilities (such as cookie and/or header) are recommended since they honor expiration settings for the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing
print $session->header()
before printing the html content?