# New session created for each instance in Perl web app using CGI::Application::Plugin::Session

Tags: perl, session, cgi, session-cookies, session-variables

Caveat: similar to, but still different from this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089657/perl-session-management)

In a home-rolled ecomm app, a session with a param of order_id is created by a Perl module common to all instances when an item is added to the shopping cart:

```
    $self->session_config(
        DEFAULT_EXPIRY => '+4h',
        COOKIE_PARAMS  => {
            -name    => 'ECOMM_SESSID',
            -expires => '+4h',
            -path    => '/',
            -domain  => '.mydomain.com',
        },
        SEND_COOKIE => 1
    );
```

This instance is fired by `cart.cgi` which calls `Cart.cgi`.

When viewing the cart, a variable dump shows

- `$self->session->param( 'order_id' )` = 4123`
- `session id = 1111111`*
- `ECOMM_SESSID` cookie in the header†

When other items are added to the cart, variable dumps continue to show the same values.

If one clicks "Checkout", `shipping.cgi` fires calling `Shipping.pm`. The existence of the  order_id param is checked in the `cgiapp_prerun` part of the module. However, a data dump shows:

- `$self->session->param( 'order_id' )` = null`
- `session id = 2222222`*
- `ECOMM_SESSID` cookie ***missing*** from the header†

A new session is being created, losing the order_id param.

Interestingly, if I go back to the cart, all the original values are there.

So, my question: how do I prevent a new session, thus preserving the old and the values needed to proceed in the checkout process?

*simplified
†in browser Inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue. PEBKAC error. The reason is was recreating two sessions with the same name but different ID's is that the shipping module was using a different domain name. So, the introduction of a new domain name was forcing a new session. Backstory: I had set this up as a staging site, but after pushing it live, forgot to adjust the link to shipping. Finally saw it in the URL. Insert head slap